# I can't correct the OLS model with heteroskedasticity by the lmtest means

Tags: r, time-series, robust, dynamic-regression, sandwich

i'm using a selvaggio model to explain the behavior of deposits in a bank's data, and i need to use the estimated parameters, 
the problem is the heteroskedasticity that i detectect with breusch-pagan test 
        bptest(model)
and when i'm trying to use the correction with what ever methods, sandwick for example. i get the same estimated coefficients .
        coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich) 
what should i do ?